# UICollectionViewCell remove space with animation while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an issue with UICollectionViewCell design layout. I need to remove space with animation while scrolling between UICollectionView Cell, I have try some delegate method of UICollectionView like -

- CollectionView - minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex
- CollectionView - minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex
- UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
- scrollViewDidEndDragging

but unable to up to the mark. here is the code:

```
  - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    float cellWidth = screenWidth / 2.1; //Replace the divisor with the column count requirement. Make sure to have it in float.
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);

    return size;
 }

  - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section 
 {
    return 1.0;
 }

 - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section 
 {
   return 1.0;
 }

 // Layout: Set Edges
 - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section 
 {
   return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);  // top, left, bottom, right
 }

 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
 {
   UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0); // after scroll cell space not remove. 
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Put some code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to change layout attributes of a collection view and animate the change, the best way is calling `setLayout:animated:`.

So like this -

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0;
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0;
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);

UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:frame collectionViewLayout:layout]
```

And then whenever you want to change it, just call the `setLayout:animated:` method:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
initialLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0;
initialLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 7.0;
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(newCellWidth, newCellHeight);

[collectionView setLayout:layout animated:YES];
```